# How to add or mark source or domain to land in desired Gmail tab?

Tags: gmail, email-client

I want Medium to land in my socials tab.

How do I set or mark Medium emails to go there?

Comment: Can you clarify what you Medium is? If you are talking about a website, you can set a filter to always display in your Social tab.

Comment: yes it's a website. how can i set the filter to always display in my social tab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create a custom search in Gmail.

To create a custom search, click on the arrow on the right hand side of the search bar on your Gmail.

[image]
(disregard the coloring around the box, I have a custom background theme on mine.)

After clicking the arrow on the right hand side, (the arrow next to the search icon) the dropdown screen will open.

[image]

Choose the parameters you want in your filter then on the bottom right click `Create filter with this search` and then in the filter options you can click `Categorize As`

[image]

Comment: i'm stuck on step 0. how do you create a custom search?

Comment: click the down arrow in the search bar in your gmail. I added a photo above.

Comment: Thank you so much. Boy, have I been missing out on some kickass Gmail features for years! I really think Google products in general could use better UX (like youtube settings? what a mess!)